# Correct Association Between Models in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have a Record model and I want to create a Field model such that a given Record `has_many` Fields. Similarly I want each field to be associated with a Tag such that each Field `has_one` Tag. But each Tag can be reused many times between Field objects.

In this case would I just say that a Tag `belongs_to_many` Fields? Likewise would it be right to say that the Field `belongs_to_many` Records?

(Ultimately I want the Record object to be a container for multiple Fields. I envision having a form where I can dynamically add new Field and Tag, so that a Record might look like:

```
Record 1
    Tag 1
    Field 1
    Tag 2
    Field 2
    ...
```

where each Tag can either be pulled from a pre-existing pool or created on the fly) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would highly recommend reading RoR Guide on Associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Whether you are new or need a touch up on using Associations in RoR, read that guide.

Your question seems to be more of a logic question, but I'll start with the
code for it:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :fields
...

class Field < ActiveRecord:Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :records
   belongs_to :tag
...

class Tag < ActiveRecord:Base
   has_many :fields
...
```

Each Record connects to many different fields, and each field connects to many different Records.  This is a classic example of a many to many association.  The logic in your code when you actually use these models is what will make the Record Model seem like a container (Because technically you could say a Field is a container for many records).

Each Field will have 1 Tag associated with it, but that same Tag could be used with any number of fields (You could say the Fields are **reusing** the tags).  This is a one to many association.  When making this connection you would use belongs_to in the Field model, and has_many in the Tag model.

Since Tag is connected to the Field Model, the logic you are looking for: A Record is a container for Fields and Tags, makes sense with this setup.

Here is a simple example of fetching a Tag inside a record:

```
#Returns the Tag Associated with the first field
#"inside" the first Record in the database.

Record.first.fields.first.tag
```

Likewise, one could easily go the opposite direction:

```
Tag.first.fields.first.records.first
```

Make sure to leverage the Rails commands via command line to quickly setup your migrations and models.  As far as options on how you want your associations to handle things when one as deleted, saved, and so on, just read the guide at the top to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Ben. The only thing that gets me confused is the HABTM association that you setup between the Record and Field models. I'm confused because I was thinking that a Record can have many Fields, but each given Field would belong to only a single Record- in other words when we talk about associations, are we viewing associations through the perspective of a single instance of the model or more generally through the perspective of each model's class? (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: Indeed.  If you wanted a Field to be unique to each record, then each Field belongs_to a Record, and a Record has_many Fields.  For some reason I thought you wanted each Field to possibly be connected to different Records.  Changing this won't affect the Tag setup in any way, because they can still be connected to many different Fields, despite those Fields being Unique to a Record.  Hope this helps.